# Can other adjectives be substituted in "Left you awed"?

Tags: word-choice, idioms, participial-adjectives

[In awe](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+awe) is an idiom that means:

> Having a great amount of respect or admiration for someone, sometimes to the point of feeling nervous or fearful around them.

It can take other forms and means the same thing, like:

- It left you [**in awe / awed**].
- That always leaves you [**in awe / awed**].

As "awed" is a participle adjective, can I substitute other synonyms to it with preserving the indicated meaning of its origin, such as:

> It left you **stupefied**.

and

> It left you **alarmed**.

**?**

I'm aware that those two, even if they are considered synonyms to "awed" according to [Thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/awed?s=t), mean different things.

Comment: Yes, you can substitute other past participles in this sentence. No, the meaning won't be the same.

Comment: Thank you JavaLatte. Would they also be substituted in the structure "left you **in awe**", like: "It left you **in stupefy/alarm**" And, would they mean the same thing in their structure "It left **stupified/alarmed**"?

Comment: Yes you can, if you use the right noun form. alarm and fear both work, but stupefy is not a noun form- use the corresponding noun, stupefaction, instead.